# WP7 updating UI dynamically without blocking thread

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am making sort of a karaoke app, where I need to tie in timestamped text-data with audio data. I have 2 lists to indicate start and end of audio timespans and text string indices. The issue that I am facing is I don't know how to update the `highlighted text` based on current `media element's POSITION` property.

WP7 doesn't have the Marker reached event (  [which silverlight has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.95).aspx)  ). So I was considering use of a  [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.95).aspx). the issue with this is that the `ticks` that I want are non-uniform, and if I update the `interval` property every tick, the accuracy of the timer will fall greatly, as the media element's position and timer's tick will fall out of sync pretty easily.

Any idea how I get create my event similar to `MarkerReached` event of the Media element ? 
Thank you-Egon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have some form of data structure that tells you where the markers are in the audio stream, so why not use a `DispatcherTimer` with a fixed **Interval** (say 500 milliseconds) and simply check against this data structure to see if you've reached a marker?

Comment: bad on battery :( though you are right UI blocking and other nasty effects are avoided.

Comment: I'm open to alternative suggestions ;)